# Error parsing proxy URL. Bad port number

Tags: linux, http, networking, proxy, wget

When I use wget command in RHEL 6.5, getting the error

`Error parsing proxy URL. Bad port number`.

The command used to set the proxy was

`export http_proxy="http_proxy://username:password@address:port/"`.

Yes I know this issue can be resolved by using

`http_proxy=address wget --proxy-user=username --proxy-password=<password> url`.

But I want to install a package and during installation, it will need to download few other packages. so the proxy should be already set and ready before the installation. How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The password I used caused this issue as it had a `#` in it. I replaced `#` with `%23` [UTF encoding] and now this is working fine.

Comment: Had the exact same issue, saved me a lot of trouble. Somehow yum is fine with it but wget isn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make us Use of "--no-proxy" 
Example : wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub  --no-proxy

This will elimimate the current proxy and try to download what ever we need..

Comment: I think the problem here is one needs to use proxy, because needed sites are blocked without it.

Answer (score 0):

I set up the proxy on Ubuntu using general system settings (*manual* option).

The problem was I pasted the proxy URL with a port, while the port is also separately specified there, in different field.

[image]